# Infinite Date loop on one server but works on other and localhost

Tags: php, infinite-loop

here is a small code in php which works on my localhost machine but not on my server.

```
$frm = strtotime('30-10-2014');
$tod = strtotime('06-11-2014');
do{
        $fromdate = date('d-m-Y',$frm);

        $frm =strtotime($fromdate) + 86400;
        echo $fromdate."<br/>";
}while($frm < $tod);
```

1) http://perfectwebsolutions.dx.am/dateloop.php (WorksFine)
2) http://worldpensonline.com/dateloop.php  (Infiniteloop)

Comment: Does your localhost and server have the same locale settings?

Comment: where can i find locale settigns on web server because i'm using default settings for 3 of them i mean dx.am server .com server and localhost (XAMPP)

Comment: Why don't you just do `$frm += 86400;`?

Comment: it will give the same result.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/locale.getdefault.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this at the start

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Berlin');
```

Or change to your prefered timezone.

I think this should do the trick, if not, let me know.

Comment: after adding this line u gave site give proper dates now.